# Cant get any data from server as a response

Tags: typescript, axios, response, next.js13, http-status-code-500

I want to receive a message back from the server side. I'm using typescript, nexApi and axios.

Im trying to call the function like this:

```
  const createNft = async () => {
    
    try {
      
      const messageToSign = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/teszt');
          console.log(messageToSign);
}catch (e: any) {
      console.error(e.message, "Problem here!!!!");
    }
  };
```

my route.ts is looks like this:

```
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest &{session: Session}, res: NextApiResponse) {
    console.log("Im here!");
    try {
        const message = {contractAddress, id: uuidv4()};
        req.session.set("message", message);
        await req.session.save();
        res.json(message);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error ,"Problem there !")
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error :
[Error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9cRT.png)

My VS Code console shows this: Error: No response is returned from route handler '...\app\api\teszt\route.ts'. Ensure you return a `Response` or a `NextResponse` in all branches of your handler.

I tried to pass only dummy data, but the result is the same.